# Howto add a custom border to a FormBorderStyle=None - form?

Tags: vb.net, border, formborderstyle

I have a form with the property FormBorderStyle set to 'None' and with a custom bar on top side for dragging and buttons.

Now I'd like to give the form a border because it's a child form and the parent form has the same background color as the child, so it's hard to see the child form.
And no, I can't/won't change the background color.

Help

Comment: Are the form width and height fixed?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way without a need to set a background image and/or fixed sized form. So this is the most proper and simple way I guess. Say you have a form named `Form1`, all you need to do is:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```

An alternative, if you want to use the default border provided by your Windows version:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    Me.Text = ""
    Me.ControlBox = False
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your first method, but the paint event isn't triggered when loading the form.

Comment: Nvm, If there are panels on the form, it doesn't paint.

Comment: The first approach can get you a very nice crisp border with single pixel width. I used this approach in WinForms C#/.NET 4.5.2, and found that the form paint handler gets called for every child element on the form. So I added "if (e.ClipRectangle.X == 0)" before ControlPaint.DrawBorder to ensure only the form received a border.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a `BackgroundImage` transparent except in the borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Visual Basic .NET Power Packs** which you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ph/download/details.aspx?id=25169). It has this Control called `LineShape` that you can put onto your border-less form's edges, like this one program that I am currently working on. [image: Notice that the borders of the form are just LineShape.]

The north border is just a `LineShape` with a `BorderWidth` set to `60` and the other borders' `BorderWidth`s are set to `10`.

Comment: The link is expired

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on the form paint event:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Black, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
```

This will draw the client border only, also if you are resizing the form, or maximizing the form use `Me.Refresh()` on form resize events so that the form redraws its borders.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the answer by theGD, I did the same thing for a TableLayouPanel on a form:

```
Private Sub TableLayoutPanel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles TableLayoutPanel1.Paint
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.DarkOrange, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```